# NSTextField Retina Font Size Issue

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am encountering a very weird issue with `NSTextField` font rendering.

The `NSTextField` is inside an `NSTableCellView` of an `NSOutlineView`.
On my main machine that has no Retina display (external), the font size looks normal.

However, If I switch to my MacBook 12" with a Retina display, the same cell renders the text inside its `NSTextField` smaller. It baffles me, because I have another outline view in the app that is not affected by this issue. I also made sure I have nothing special configured for the text field by dragging in a new one from the palette.

I also manually subclassed the `NSTextField` to see who sets the font size down from `13pt` to `11pt`, and the call comes from the system framework.

What could affect the font size on retina displays?

Comment: @matt Nah, because the system changes it AFTER i return the cell from the delegate. `wantsLayer` is not set.

Comment: Yes, i tried that already and it works if I override the accessor. However I'd prefer to solve the root cause of this instead of creating a subclass just to work around it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this doesn't have to do with Retina displays. It's just different settings in the two accounts.

In particular, I suspect the outline view which is having this issue is a source list. Its `selectionHighlightStyle` is `.sourceList`. Source lists adjust their size based on System Preferences > General > Sidebar icon size. (Changing the icon size also changes the label size, too.) You can change that setting and your app should resize the source list items, live.

Ideally, your source lists should honor this setting. So, you should accept this behavior. If you don't want it, you might reconsider making your outline view a source list.

If you really want to keep the outline view as a source list but override this behavior, you can do that on an app-wide basis. You can have your app set a value for itself in `UserDefaults` for the key `NSTableViewDefaultSizeMode`. Small is 1, Medium is 2, Large is 3.

Comment: You are right! It was set to `small` on the retina device and to `medium` on the other machine. I have 2 outline views thought, both are source lists. Only one of them exhibits this behavior though.

Comment: Did you connect the `textField` outlet of the table cell view to the text field in both cases? That outlet is what Cocoa uses to apply the preference setting. I guess leaving that outlet disconnected is another way to prevent the issue. However, connecting that outlet has some other useful effects, like improving accessibility.

Comment: They are both connected. The only difference is that one text field is editable, the other is not. I changed the other to be also editable, but it didn't change anything.